# Sharing a cshtml file with UI designer team who doesn't have .NET IDE

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We are working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and taking advantage of Razor syntax to resolve paths and what not.

We are also employing a UI design team who is responsible for maintaining the design of our pages through the use of CSS and modifying the HTML in the cshtml pages.

The problem is, they work exclusively on Mac laptops without access to a web server or a .NET IDE.

Initially, they were just providing us a straight .html file along with a .css file and we were manually merging in their work into our ASP.NET solution (e.g., replacing paths with Razor markup, etc), but as the project grows and we become more involved, we are looking for a solution that will save us from these manual merges.

I was thinking I could create some kind include script that would rewrite the paths depending on whether the UI designers were editing the file, or the .NET devs, but this seems archaic.

Anyone out there been in this situation before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor is a templating language, and a pretty small one at that.  Could your UI team familiarize themselves with enough of it to deal with their own links?  I'm sure they are familar with your view hierarchy since they are going to be building it, so it shouldn't be much of a leap to explain how controller and action paths work.

Razor files can be edited outside of a .NET IDE just fine...any old text editor will work since it's not like there's anything you have to compile.  You could provide them with an instance that they could copy their files to via a shared drive (cifs) to test them on.  I don't see any reason for your UI team to be required to use Visual Studio.

Comment: We eventually ended up letting the design guys edit the files externally, and then pushing them up to our dev environment, via a share, where we could verify their changes. It wasn't ideal, but since our designers use Macs, we didn't have much choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename your `.cshtml` file to `.aspx` and reload it in VS and design away. when you are done, rename it to `.cshtml`

Comment: That is not necessary you can right click .cshtml files and "Open With..." there will be the "HTML webforms editor".